# Python cannot open file ('Directory'): No such file or directory

Tags: python

I am trying to use a repository from this link

https://github.com/zarroboogs/p4g-saveconv#moving-converted-saves-to-ps-vita

I've managed to successfully clone the repository and it instructs you to run the command

```
python convert_vita2pc.py [--custom-diff {disable,enable}] save_dir
```

but when I do I get the error

```
Python cannot open file ('Directory'): No such file or directory
```

Could someone help and teach me how to properly do this?

Comment: how did you run `python convert_vita2pc.py` ? Did you use your existing directory as argument ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that Python script cannot find the direcotry named 'Directory' (I assume 'Directory' is the <save_dir> from guilde on that link you provided).

So maybe you can try to add an absolute path to that directory (on linux machines go in the desired directory ('Directory') and type 'pwd' command. Then copy the path to the <save_dir> place at the end of that convert script).